# Fetching 2 times but cant set the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

in 'fetchData' function im fetching an initialUrl which has list of names and URLs. These urls will be giving me the actual data i need, of course im using returning datas of initialUrl. 
 - Im sending those names and urls in order to use urls again, and mapping those datas in 'loadingPokemon' function. In that function, im mapping through incoming datas, getting urls, fetching them with axios, and setting fetched datas into 'pokeDatasDatas' with spread operator, console.log below gives the datas i need (20 total, increases from 0 to 20 in each step) 
 - But does this after initial render. I couldnt set my state 'setPokemonData' with those datas. 
 Also the screen gives an empty white screen... 
 Im aware my variable names are kind of messy, sorry for that...

Here are my state variables;

```
const [pokemonData, setPokemonData] = useState([]);
const [nextUrl, setNextUrl] = useState('');
const [prevUrl, setPrevUrl] = useState('');
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
const initialUrl = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/';
```

**So here is my useEffect ;**

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    let response = await axios.get(initialUrl);
    setNextUrl(response.next);
    setPrevUrl(response.previous);
    //console.log(response.data.results); name ve url veriyor
    //setPokemonData(response.data.results);
    let a = await loadingPokemon(response.data.results);
    console.log(a);
    setPokemonData(a);
    setLoading(false);
    };

    fetchData();
    }, []);
```

**and my 'loadingPokemon' function**

```
const loadingPokemon = async (datas) => {
  let pokeDatasDatas = [];
  const pokemons = await datas.map(async (data) => {
    let pokemonRecords = await data.url;

    let pokeDatas = await axios.get(pokemonRecords);
    pokeDatasDatas = [...pokeDatasDatas, pokeDatas.data];
    console.log(pokeDatasDatas);
  });
  console.log(pokeDatasDatas);
  //setPokemonData(pokeDatasDatas);
  return pokeDatasDatas;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

First I carried 'loadingPokemon' function to inside of 'useEffect'

After that, i made 2 empty arrays, first im mapping through incoming parameter (datas) to get only URLs and make an new array of it. Because 'datas' were holding 2 objects; name and URL.
I mapped through and pushed every data into 'pokemonRecords' and made new array.
After that, i needed actual datas from each URL in 'pokemonRecords'. So for each record i need to fetch data from that URL with axios, and push every returning data into 'pokemonDatas' array which holds every URL's datas now.

```
  const loadingPokemon = async (datas) => {
   let pokemonRecords = [];
   let pokemonDatas = [];
   datas.map((data) => {
    pokemonRecords.push(data.url);
   
   });
    

   pokemonRecords.forEach(async (record) => {
    let pokemonDatasDatas = await axios.get(record);

    console.log(pokemonDatasDatas.data);
    pokemonDatas.push(pokemonDatasDatas.data);
   });
    
   };
```